# Access custom_design in product list

Tags: attributes, product-list, list.phtml

I need to alter the display of products in `catalog/product/list.phtml` based on whether they have a Custom Design assigned, in Magento 1.8.

I've edited `custom_design` in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` and set "Use in Product Listing" to "Yes", reindexed, cleared cache.

But when I use:

```
// in catalog/product/list.phtml

$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
  echo $_product->getCustomDesign();
  //or
  echo $_product->getData('custom_design');
}
```

I get no output for that attribute.

I've also tried:

```
// in catalog/product/list.phtml

$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('custom_design')->load();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
  echo $_product->getCustomDesign();
  //or
  echo $_product->getData('custom_design');
}
```

But still nothing.

If I use `$_product->getCustomDesign();` in `catalog/product/view.phtml`, I get the output I expect, so I know it's the right attribute & the product has the value.

Anybody know if I'm missing anything? I've gone through the blocks/model stack and made sure that `custom_design` is being added to the list of attributes to load, as I'd expect, but if I `var_dump($_product->getData())`, it doesn't appear.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use flat tables? Rebuild the flat index then and check if the column custom_design has been added to the table catalog_product_flat_index_[store-id]

Comment: Flat tables is enabled, but catalog_product_flat_1 (there's no catalog_product_flat_index_<id>) doesn't have 'custom_design'. Is there a way to rebuild other than just hitting 'reindex' on the Index Management page?

Comment: yes, i meant this table; added another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the product if you want to access custom attributes.
Something like

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('custom_design');

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())
   echo $product ->getCustomDesign();
   //or
   echo $product ->getData('custom_design');
}
```

should work

Comment: Thanks. I thought `Use in Product Listing` was enough (this isn't a custom attribute - "Custom Design" is a core attribute), but it does work with loading the product.

I don't seem to have to use `addAttributeToSelect` - it does seem like that's being taken care of by the `Use in Product Listing` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You were right that you need to set the attribute to `"Used in product listings" => "Yes"`. After that, you need to rebuild the flat index, and the table `catalog_product_flat_[store-id]` should have a new column called `custom_design`. You can rebuild the index in the backend (which tends to run forever or crash on big catalogs), you can use a custom PHP-script, you can use the built-in shell command in `MAGENTO_ROOT/shell/indexer.php` or a tool like `n98-magerun`.

The answer by Anja solves the problem by simply calling `load()` on the product. This is a typical "It's-not-correct-but-it-works"-solution, here's why:

Taken from [this very insightful article by Vinai Kopp](http://vinaikopp.com/2014/06/09/preloading-for-scalabiliy/):

> If there is a single product in the collection, this code block will
>   cause 4 queries to be executed. If there are 100 products in the
>   collection, there would be 202 queries being executed (2 for the
>   collection and 2 for each product: 2 + 100*2).

IMO the only position where `load()` is allowed to be in a loop is an export script where performance doesn't matter. As you stated in your question, you want to use this code in a product list in the frontend for real visitors, and once there are more than a few of them, this will lead to serious performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, and I did want to avoid the `load()` in the loop. I've double-checked that the attribute (`"Edit Product Attribute "Custom Design"`) has `"Used in product listings" => "Yes"`, and I just ran the indexer in the shell: `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`, and the output includes: `Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully` and `Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully`. There's no `custom_design` column though - [Pastebin output from `SHOW TABLES FROM catalog_product_flat_1`](http://pastebin.com/g7ALuC4p)